# Upload file without manually constructing HTTP POST with "multipart/form-data; boundary"

Tags: ios, iphone, file-upload, upload, multipartform-data

As iOS programming newbie I wonder, if there is a clean way to upload a file from iPhone to a PHP script - **without** constructing an awkward custom POST request with [multipart/form-data; boundary](http://www.iriphon.com/2011/11/09/ios-uploading-an-image-from-your-iphone-to-a-server/) stuff.

Preferrably using Apple libraries (iOS 7 only is ok) only or at least some clean open source code.

The PHP part I can create myself, but for the Objective C part I've only been able to find examples, which "reinvent" the POST method...

Comment: If you don't want to use multipart/form-data. You can convert the image in base64 string and can use simple post method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is a popular open source library to handle something like this.

Comment: AFNetworking may also be an alternative. Check (http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course) This tutorials.